# Re-title list of plots with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, plot

I have generated histograms using ggplot2. I would like to rename the plots as the last step after I create them. I was thinking of using a for loop but can't quite get it to work.

The plots are contained in the variable `hist` which is of class `"list"` and I access them by typing:

```
hist$A
hist$B
hist$C

## rename plots as the last step 

name <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (i in seq_along(hist)) {
  hist[[i]] +
    labs(title = name[[i]])
}

# this code works but I can't replicate it in a for loop
hist$C +
  labs(
    title = name[3])
```

I would like the title of `hist$B` to be `"B"`.

Comment: I think you wanted to have different titles rather than different names. At least I hope I read your intent correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to assign back to the items inside `hist`:

```
name <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (i in seq_along(hist)) {
  hist[i] <- hist[[i]] +
    labs(title = name[i])
}
```

And don't forget that in order to produce output on a graphics device you need to `print` a `grid`-graphics object, which ggplot items are.

Comment: I think you may need `hist[[i]] <- ` and `name[i]` instead.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe. Wasn't sure which one to use for the assignment and there was no MCVE to test with. You're definitely right about the selection of names, edited.